# Get body of function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tostring

i am trying to get the body of a function in JavaScript but am unable to do so. Let's say I wanted to see the function body of the native toUpperCase() function of the String object:

```
document.write(String.prototype.toUpperCase.toString()); 
// returns function toUpperCase() { [native code] }
```

I tried this in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, all return the same thing. How do I access what that [native code] contents is?

*** update ***

The reason I stumbled onto this question, is because I was trying to do the following:

If I have two functions, one of which I want to invoke on the other, I want to access the first function's return value in the second, so that I can do function1().function2(). For example:

```
// create a global function that returns a value
function returnValue() {
   x = "john";
   return x;
}

// create a function that converts that value to uppercase
   function makeUpperCase(){
   return this.toUpperCase(); 
   // "this" obviously doesn't work, but "this" is where I wanted to
   // access the return value of a function I'm invoking makeUpperCase() on.
}
```

So I wanted to see how a function like toUpperCase() accesses the return value of a function it is invoked on.

Comment: you can't - at least not with JavaScript... you would need to load the JavaScript-implementation (usually some DLL) into a disassembler...

Comment: In your example you can use makeUpperCase.apply(returnValue()). This will make the 'this' in makeUpperCase be the returned string, thus making it call the string's toUpperCase method

Comment: Doesn't sound like you really need the body. I think you should look into function chaining.

Comment: In your case, you can do `returnValue().toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function to `String.prototype`, then you can "chain" your function calls.

```
String.prototype.makeUpperCase = function(){
  // 'this' is the string that 'makeUpperCase' was called on
  return this.toUpperCase();
};

var y = returnValue().makeUpperCase();
```

Chaining works by having the functions be part of the object, `String.prototype` in this case.  So, when you return that object (a string), you can call another function on it ("chaining").